# What name can I use for a cocone over the mapping cone diagram?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, terminology

In homotopy theory, the *mapping cone* of a continuous map $f\colon X \to Y$ is the homotopy pushout over the following span:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@VVV \\
\{*\}
\end{CD}
$$

I.e., it is universal among all squares of the form
$$
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\{*\}@>>> Z
\end{CD}
$$
where the square commutes up to homotopy.

But what is a good name for such an object $Z$?  Normally, I would call it a **cocone**, but I would rather not use the word *cone* to mean two different things.

*Square* and *cospan* are possibilities, but they seem a bit too general: I want to refer specifically to cocones for the first diagram.

Is there a good alternative word?

Comment: 'Span' is probably not good.  Of course it's unlikely to conflict with the linear-algebraic terminology, but it already has meaning in the category-theoretic context:  [n-Lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span).

Comment: @LSpice That's my mistake - I meant 'cospan' (over the objects $\{*\}$ and $Y$).

Comment: Sure, but my impression was that '(co)span' was the name for two arrows among three objects, not four arrows among four objects.  If you're familiar with the useage, though, then I trust your sense of it more than mine.

Comment: Often $Z$ is called a "cofiber" of the map $f$ -- is this terminology not suitable?

Comment: Why not just cone of (or over) $f$?

Comment: @LSpice Your impression is the same as mine.  $Y$, $Z$ and $\{*\}$ form a cospan in the usual sense.  I suppose I meant 'cospan that we can attach to the existing span in such a way that the resulting square commutes', but since that wasn't immediately clear to you, that probably means that it's not a good name.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The point is that I'm already using the word 'cone' to refer to the universal object for this diagram.  The unfortunate coincidence between the names of a cone in the topological sense and a cone in the category-theoretic sense is why I'm looking for an alternative name.

Comment: @TylerLawson Thanks, although it looks as though 'cofiber' is normally used for the universal such $Z$ (in this case, the mapping cone) rather than an arbitary one making the square commute.

Comment: Just an observation: any object $Z$ fits your definition, since you can always take the right-hand vertical map to be trivial.

Comment: @JohnGowers Ah, I did not understand that you were looking for a name for a generic object in the undercategory. My apologies.

Comment: @MarkGrant When I say 'the object $Z$', I really mean the object $Z$ plus the two morphisms $Y\to Z$ and $\{*\}\to Z$.

Comment: Mine was exactly the same misunderstanding. Well, in that case $Y\to Z$ might be referred to as something like "contractor of $f$", or "nullifier" of it, or even "killer" or something. What I certainly encountered is the situation with two parallel arrows $X\rightrightarrows Y$; then one says that $Y\to Z$ coequalizes them (and the universal such is then the coequalizer). So maybe similarly you could say that $Y\to Z$ cones $f$, or caps it off, or something like that...

Comment: In fact in any preadditive category it would be reasonable to say that $Y\to Z$ belongs to the right annihilator of $f$